# IPTables - allow connection from only one random IP simultaneously

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Please tell me how to limit the connection to the server's listening port to only one random IP address, if a TCP-Syn comes from any other second one, then it is reset, if there are no connections to this port, allow it.

In short, connections should only be allowed to one source address at a time.

Answer (score 0):

All is easy:

> sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport "SERVICE_PORT" -m connlimit
> --connlimit-above 0 --connlimit-mask 0 -j REJECT